# 404 page not found the page you requested was not found in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

**Our code are as below**

application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://myworldmirror.com/';  
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php/home';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
```

application/config/database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'newsels1',
    'password' => 'newsels1',
    'database' => 'newsels1',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysql',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

**Output**

When I open this url "http://myworldmirror.com/", the output below is shown

[image: Error image]

Comment: change `config['index_page'] = 'index.php/home';`  to `config['index_page'] = '';`

Comment: Hello mohammad try this code but show same error

Comment: Solved my problem : Thank you bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php/home';` **To** `$config['index_page'] = '';`

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Check Your default controller value in **application/config/routes.php**

**`$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`**

check **application/controllers/Welcome.php exist or not** otherwise change **`$route['default_controller']`** value as your requirement

Comment: Are you sure you can set valid value of default_controller ?

Comment: Which value of $route['default_controller'] ?

Comment: $route['default_controller']  =  'home'  &  controller/home.php is available

Comment: Please rename controller/home.php To controller/Home.php

Comment: Solved my problem : Thank you bro

Answer (score 2):

Since I was not able to provide accurate solution to your problem, Please try below methods.Any one of the mothod works then we can find a solution.

1. remove your .htacces file and update $config['index_page'] = ' '; now just try the URL http://myworldmirror.com/index.php/home or http://myworldmirror.com/index.php. (If this method works then you have a problem with your .htaccess file).
2. In config/database.php just replace 'dbdriver' => 'mysql', with 'dbdriver' => 'mysqli' and try.

Please let me know the result.

Comment: Solved my problem : Thank you bro

Answer (score 2):

`http://myworldmirror.com/Home` is work .

you change

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
```

to

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Comment: @NxsolTeam Fixed now ?

Comment: Solved my problem : Thank you bro